# Django Sum float values

Tags: python, django, model

I have model in Django which have three fields. Float, and two CharFields. I need to sum the float fields by the other two.

models.py

```
class Hours(model.Model):
    hours_worked = models.FloatField()
    order_number = models.CharField()
    oper = models.CharField()
```

What I need to do is go through all data in DB and sum `hours_worked` for the same order_number+oper.
So let say I have in db 4 records:

```
|hours_worked|order_number|oper|
|------------|------------|----|
|           4|         252|  10|
|           8|         320|  20|
|           8|         252|  10|
|           6|         252|  20|
```

And I need to return queryset of three objects like this:

```
|hours_worked|order_number|oper|
|------------|------------|----|
|          12|         252|  10|
|           8|         320|  20|
|           6|         252|  20|
```

Is there any easy way how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible solutions (there are certainly others)

#### using [django-group-by](https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by)

```
from django_group_by import GroupByMixin

class GroupedHoursQuerySet(QuerySet, GroupByMixin):
    def select_related(self, *fields):
        try:
            return super().select_related(*fields)  # once grouping was applied, select_related will fail
        except TypeError:
            return self

class GroupedHours(Hours):
    objects = GroupedHoursQuerySet.as_manager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

and to query the data:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg, StringAgg
from django.db.models import Sum

qs = GroupedHours.objects.group_by('order_number', 'oper').annotate(
    hours_worked=Sum('hours_worked'),
    pks=ArrayAgg('id'),
    pk=StringAgg(Cast('id', output_field=TextField()), '-'),
).distinct()
```

The objects in the returned queryset have the same attributes as the original model but `hours_worked` contains the sum:

```
for gh in qs:
    print(f'Operator {gh.oper} worked {gh.hours_worked} on order {gh.order_number}')
```

#### Django's `values()`

You can of course use aggregate and annotate without the django-group-by module if you don't need Django model objects be just the actual numbers.

The following might also work (untested), refer to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for more details:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

qs = Hours.objects.values('order_number', 'oper').annotate(
    worktime=Sum('hours_worked')
```

It might be necessary to add a `.distinct()`.

This returns a dict:

```
for gh in qs:
    print(f'Operator {gh['oper']} worked {gh['hours_worked']} on order {gh['order_number']}')
```

Comment: Would not `values` and `annotate` be enough for a simple group by? Why a separate package to do that?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - depends on the use case. I like using django-group-by because it returns a queryset with django model objects, so that I can re-use most of the code already present for the regular model objects. Your comment is very valid, especially for this model with only 3 fields - so I've added a code snippet with the values solution.

Comment: That's useful, noticed a missing quote by the way near `oper` in the snippet. :)

Comment: Thanks, fixed the quote and added examples on how to access the fields/attributes to illustrate the difference between `.values()` and the other solution.

Comment: @Risadinha I have more models in the models.py and I am receiving `'Person' object has no attribute 'group_by'`. Any idea?

Comment: @pipikej the `GroupByMixin` should be a supertype of the QuerySet, and you would call it on the manager, e.g. `Person.objects.group_by`. `Person` needs to overload its `objects` attribute. I had forgotten the essential line of code in my example, sorry. I've updated my answer.